# Outlook Interop delivers different results

Tags: c#, interop, outlook

I'm using the Outlook-Interop to read some Events from different calendars and show them on a big screen. On my machine everything works fine (Outlook 2010, Win7 x64), but on the client's pc (Outlook2003, Win XP) the program doesn't find all appointments. If I add some checkboxes for debugging the tool finds between 8 and 12 Appointments (12 it should find) and without always 6. I have no idea what's going wrong, so please help me out.

Here's the code:

```
this.Appointments = new List<AppointmentItem>();

foreach (MAPIFolder folder in this.SelectedCalendars)
{
    foreach (object app in folder.Items)
    {
        if (app is AppointmentItem && ((AppointmentItem)app).Start.Date == DateTime.Now.Date)
        {
            this.Appointments.Add(((AppointmentItem)app));
        }
    }
}

this.Appointments.Sort(
    delegate(AppointmentItem App1, AppointmentItem App2)
    {
        return App1.Start.CompareTo(App2.Start);
    });
```

**Update**

I have some new Information. Got this Exception. Any idea how to handle with?

(I translated from German to English; hope you'll understand ;))

> The COM-Object of the type "System.__ComObject" couldn't be
>   changed to the Interfacetype
>   "Microsoft.Office.Interop.AppointmentItem.
>       This procedure couldn't be run, because the Queryinterface-Call to the
>       COM-Component for the interface with IID
>   "{00063033-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}"
>        couldn't be run because of the following error:
>       Interface not supported (Exception _HRESULT:0x80004002 (E_NOINTERFACE)).

Answer (score 0):

It might be the iterator which is failing for the COM object.

Does it work if you re-write your loop to call `GetFirst()` and `GetNext()` explicitly:

```
object app = folder.Items.GetFirst();
while (app != null)
{
    if (app is AppointmentItem && ((AppointmentItem)app).Start.Date == DateTime.Now.Date)
    {
        this.Appointments.Add(((AppointmentItem)app));
    }
    app = folder.Items.GetNext();
}
```

You can also try to filter the Items collection on the start date.

```
var items = folder.Items.Restrict("[Start] < '01/31/2009 00:00 AM' and [Start] >= '01/30/2009 00:00 AM");
```

Comment: Hm, sry, but this couldn't solve the Problem. I start thinking that it could be a problem with Outlook/Exchange...

Comment: Does folder.Items.Count give the same number in 2003 and 2010?

Comment: The differ on every update. Also with the same Interop. So it's hard to make a comparism

Comment: A wild idea. Could it be the date filter which fails?  ((AppointmentItem)app).Start.Date == DateTime.Now.Date

Maybe one is retrieved without timezone information, so the comparison fails? If you retrieve all appointments for say one month, do you get the correct numbers then?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are bound to the 2003 version of the Office Interops which should be forwardly compatible.

Comment: Already checked. Just for fun I tried also with v14 and got the same results (FYI)